# *When* are mixed models with a lagged dependent variable inconsistent/biased?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, panel-data, consistency

Suppose panel data where multiple observations are made of units over time. Regressing a dependent variable measured at each time point on lag of the dependent variable and a unit-specific intercept (a "random effect") - perhaps with an overall intercept for the grand mean - leads to inconsistency and bias of the estimator.

- Does this apply in the case of 2 time periods?
- Does this apply when the independent variable of interest is randomly assigned? In other words, we are controlling for the lag to improve precision.

Comment: Related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69614/7071)

Comment: Unfortunately this is simply for the fixed effect case. This is also similarly related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs