# Controlling covariates in linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, sums-of-squares

I have made these two models:

```
(model1 <- summary(lm(mpg ~ drat + wt + cyl, mtcars)))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ drat + wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2944 -1.5576 -0.4667  1.5678  6.1014 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  39.7677     6.8729   5.786 3.26e-06 ***
drat         -0.0162     1.3231  -0.012 0.990317    
wt           -3.1947     0.8293  -3.852 0.000624 ***
cyl          -1.5096     0.4464  -3.382 0.002142 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.613 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8302,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.812 
F-statistic: 45.64 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 6.569e-11


(model2 <- summary(lm(mpg ~  wt + cyl + drat, mtcars)))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl + drat, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2944 -1.5576 -0.4667  1.5678  6.1014 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  39.7677     6.8729   5.786 3.26e-06 ***
wt           -3.1947     0.8293  -3.852 0.000624 ***
cyl          -1.5096     0.4464  -3.382 0.002142 ** 
drat         -0.0162     1.3231  -0.012 0.990317    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.613 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8302,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.812 
F-statistic: 45.64 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 6.569e-11
```

My understanding is that R uses "sequential" partitioning for the variance in `mpg`. So in `model1`, `drat` should be unadjusted, `wt` should be adjusted for `drat` and `cyl` should be adjusted for `drat` and `wt`. In `model2`, `wt` should be unadjusted, `cyl` should be adjusted for `wt` and `drat` should be adjusted for `wt` and `cyl`.

However, the coefficients in each model appear to be exactly the same, suggesting coefficients are not being adjusted at all. Are the coefficients not being adjusted at all?

Answer (score 17):

The question, as phrased, is slightly ambiguous.  It states that "the coefficients in each model appear to be exactly the same".  There are two ways that statement could be interpreted, with respect to: (1) the `Estimates` of the coefficients, or (2) the *tests* of the coefficients.

1. Regarding the `Estimates` of the coefficients, they are being adjusted for the other variables in the model, but you don't see any difference because you have the same variables in both `model1` and `model2`; the order they are listed in doesn't matter.  The parameter estimates will only differ if the variables are correlated *and* the sets of variables that are included in the models differ.  Consider:

   ```
   model1 <- lm(mpg ~ drat + wt + cyl,  mtcars)
   model2 <- lm(mpg ~  wt + cyl + drat, mtcars)
   model3 <- lm(mpg ~  wt       + drat, mtcars)
   cor(mtcars$wt, mtcars$cyl)
   # [1] 0.7824958
   summary(model2)
   # Coefficients:
   #               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   #   (Intercept)  39.7677     6.8729   5.786 3.26e-06 ***
   #   wt           -3.1947     0.8293  -3.852 0.000624 ***
   #   cyl          -1.5096     0.4464  -3.382 0.002142 ** 
   #   drat         -0.0162     1.3231  -0.012 0.990317    
   summary(model3)
   # Coefficients:
   #               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   #   (Intercept)   30.290      7.318   4.139 0.000274 ***
   #   wt            -4.783      0.797  -6.001 1.59e-06 ***
   #   drat           1.442      1.459   0.989 0.330854
   ```

   Notice that the `Estimate` for `wt` is `-3.1974` in `model2` and `-4.783` in `model3`.  To learn more about how the parameter estimates for variables can change depending on whether a correlated variable is included or not, it may help you to read by answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830/7290).
2. Regarding the *tests* of the coefficients, it depends on which function you use to get your output.  You used `summary()`.  What is reported then are the $t$-tests associated with the parameter estimates.  Those are not computed by [partitioning sums of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_sums_of_squares).  However, they are equivalent to $F$-tests using **type III SS**.  The order variables are listed in doesn't matter for $t$-tests or $F$-tests that are based on type III SS.  You can also use `anova()` to get significance tests of your parameter estimates.  *That* is where R uses **type I SS**.  And because type I SS are sequential, the order the variables are listed in does matter (although again, only if the variables are correlated).  Consider:

   ```
   summary(model1)
   # Coefficients:
   #               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   #   (Intercept)  39.7677     6.8729   5.786 3.26e-06 ***
   #   drat         -0.0162     1.3231  -0.012 0.990317    
   #   wt           -3.1947     0.8293  -3.852 0.000624 ***
   #   cyl          -1.5096     0.4464  -3.382 0.002142 ** 
   summary(model2)
   # Coefficients:
   #               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   #   (Intercept)  39.7677     6.8729   5.786 3.26e-06 ***
   #   wt           -3.1947     0.8293  -3.852 0.000624 ***
   #   cyl          -1.5096     0.4464  -3.382 0.002142 ** 
   #   drat         -0.0162     1.3231  -0.012 0.990317    
   anova(model1)
   # Analysis of Variance Table
   #             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
   #   drat       1 522.48  522.48  76.525 1.691e-09 ***
   #   wt         1 334.33  334.33  48.967 1.308e-07 ***
   #   cyl        1  78.07   78.07  11.435  0.002142 ** 
   #   Residuals 28 191.17    6.83                      
   anova(model2)
   # Analysis of Variance Table
   #             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
   #   wt         1 847.73  847.73 124.1627 8.382e-12 ***
   #   cyl        1  87.15   87.15  12.7645  0.001304 ** 
   #   drat       1   0.00    0.00   0.0001  0.990317    
   # Residuals 28 191.17    6.83
   ```

   Notice that the $p$-value for `wt` is `0.000624` in both `summary()` outputs, but is `1.308e-07` in `anova(model1)` and it `8.382e-12` in `anova(model2)`.  To learn more about sums of squares in general, it may help to read my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/7290).  Lastly, note that you can get an ANOVA table in R that uses other types of SS, such as II and III, by using `Anova()` in the `car` package.

Comment: Hmmm…regarding your first point R in Action (2011, Kabacoff) states something different. He says order matters and in general, models should be ordered as covariates, main effects, interactions. In the model y~a+b+a:b, a will be unadjusted, b will adjust for a and a:b will adjust for a and b. He states adjustment should occur if (a) unequal number of observations in any predictor OR (b) covariates are present

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean, @luciano. If that is what he says, he's wrong, although there may be some ambiguity in the way he put something & he didn't quite mean that. You can see in the examples what changes & what doesn't, & under what circumstances. All those examples were simply run in R & cut&pasted here. You can run them yourself & get the same results.

Comment: Having re-read Kabacoff, I think he's just refering to sum of squares in an ANOVA table, not the coefficients. My mistake

Comment: I suspected something like that might be true, @luciano, it's very easy to miss something subtle like that. Let me know if you need anything else.