# Linear OLS v Mixed-Effects Model with Correlated Regressors

Tags: r, linear-model, mixed-model

Reading this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830/67822) by @gung brought me to try to reproduce his superb illustrations, and led ultimately to question something I had read or heard, but that I'd like to understand more intuitively: Why is an OLS `lm` controlling for a correlated variable better (can I say 'better' tentatively?) than a mixed-effects model with different intersects and slopes?

Here's the toy example, again trying to parallel the post quoted above:

First the data:

```
set.seed(0)    
x1 <- c(rnorm(10,3,1),rnorm(10,5,1),rnorm(10,7,1))
x2 <- rep(c(1:3),each=10)
    y1 <- 2  -0.8 * x1[1:10] + 8 * x2[1:10] +rnorm(10)
    y2 <- 6  -0.8 * x1[11:20] + 8 * x2[11:20] +rnorm(10)
    y3 <- 8  -0.8 * x1[21:30] + 8 * x2[21:30] +rnorm(10)
y <- c(y1, y2, y3)
```

And the different models:

```
library(lme4)

fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
fit3 <- lmer(y ~ x1 + (1|x2))
fit4 <- lmer(y ~ x1|x2, REML=F)
```

Comparing  Akaike information criterion (AIC) between models:

```
AIC(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4)

     df      AIC
     df      AIC
fit1  3 184.5330
fit2  4  97.6568
fit3  4 112.0120
fit4  5 114.8401
```

So it seems that the best model is `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)`, which I guess make sense given the strong correlation between `x1` and `x2` `cor(x1,x2) [1] 0.8619565`.

But the question is, What is the intuition behind this behavior, when the mixed model with varying intercepts and slopes seems to result in coefficients that fit the data beautifully?

```
coef(lmer(y ~ x1|x2))
$x2

      x1       (Intercept)
1 -1.1595730    11.37746
2 -0.2586303    19.38601
3  0.2829754    24.20038

library(lattice)    
xyplot(y ~ x1, groups = x2, pch=19,
           panel = function(x, y,...) {
             panel.xyplot(x, y,...);
             panel.abline(a=coef(fit4)$x2[1,2], b=coef(fit4)$x2[1,1],lty=2,col='blue');
             panel.abline(a=coef(fit4)$x2[2,2], b=coef(fit4)$x2[2,1],lty=2,col='magenta');
             panel.abline(a=coef(fit4)$x2[3,2], b=coef(fit4)$x2[3,1],lty=2,col='green')
           })
```

[image]

I do realize that the graphical fit of the bivariate OLS can look pretty good as well:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
plot1 <- scatterplot3d(x1,x2,y, type='h', pch=16,
              highlight.3d=T)
plot1$plane3d(fit2)
```

[image]

... and I don't know if this invalidates the question.

Comment: It doesn't change the end result in this case, but the `lmer()` fits should be fit using ML rather than REML, via [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019807/how-to-compare-a-model-with-no-random-effects-to-a-model-with-a-random-effect-us). Also note the caveats to using the AIC in a mixed model context listed at http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq.

Comment: Thank you. Would you suggest a different test? Do you think the question is still valid?

Comment: I think the question is perfectly valid. I might be able to do a proper post later, but I think the answer to the question will involve how the AIC is computed and/or whether treating `x2` as random makes theoretical and practical sense.

Comment: A few more comments about the models/data in the example:

The grouping factor `x2` only has three levels, which limits the practicality of using it as a random effect (also mentioned in the faq). Also, fitting the random slope model `fit4` without including the fixed `x1` term doesn't really make sense.

The `sleepstudy` dataset might be more appropriate, and you can tease the same thing out by comparing `Reaction ~ Days + Subject` against `Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject)`.

Comment: @alexforrence Yes. It's almost obvious now: in the mixed-effects models we get three fitted lines, one for each level of x2, but fail to encapsulate the overarching upward progression of y with x1 that is so much better represented with the plane in lm(y ~ x1 + x2). It would be awesome if you do go ahead and answer the question with this silly toy dataset, just to bring the concept home (and perhaps the grammar and interpretation of lmer). Thank you!

Comment: @alexforrence If you go ahead with a post, can you include a lmer call where the slope for x1 as the fixed effects is positive, as it is for lm(y~x1+x2)? Or is it really just not possible to reflect with lmer the positive overall correlation (independent of x2 levels) of x1 and y (cor(x1,y) [1] 0.7924759)?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a whole answer to the question, but I think the intercepts have a lot to do with how well the lm model fits. For instance, change the intercept for `y3` to 40. Or swap intercepts for `y1` and `y2`. Additionally, I think the intercepts are playing such a large role because of the small sample size (e.g. try increasing to 20 and then 100 per level, instead of 10).  Another thing to think about is whether or not you should be treating `x2` as a factor:  `lm(y ~ x1 + as.factor(x2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with the conversation in the comments, it may actually be quite obvious: in mixed-effects, the overall increasing values of $y$ with increasing $x1$ as shown in:

[image]

with a positive correlation of `cor(x1,y) [1] 0.7924759`, is nicely captured in the plane formed by `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` (depicted in the OP plots) or in the following graph:

```
library(car)
library(rgl)
scatter3d (y ∼ x1  +  x2)
rgl.snapshot(filename="scat1.png", fmt="png")
```

[image]

On the other hand, this is simply lost in `lmer` mixed-effects. Rather than a positive slope in the regression of $y$ over $x1$, all the slope coefficients are consistently negative, because at each level of stratification created by the discrete values of $x2$ (`1`, `2` and `3`), the corresponding $x1$ do slope downwards:

```
scatter3d (x=x1,y=x2,z=y, groups=as.factor(x2))
```

(source [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/amazing-interactive-3d-scatter-plots-r-software-and-data-visualization))

[image]

I tend to assume (and liked to get confirmation) that this may be substantial to the idea of mixed-effects, and that it cannot be corrected by modifying the `lmer` call synthax. I tried for instance `lmer(y ~ (x1|x2), REML=F)`, `lmer(y ~ x1 + (x1|x2), REML=F)`, among others, with conceptually similar outputs.

Leaving aside the fact that in the example in the OP each of the discrete values that $x2$ assumes as a distinct "unit" role, which is a coercion of the idea of a hierarchical model, where units are typically subjects, it is clear that a `lmer` mixed-effects model is not optimal in this situation, and that even in the case that the values of $x2$ were more 'natural' units (say, `x2==1` corresponded to `John`; `x2==2` was for `Tom`, and `x2==3` were the values for `Mary`), a linear OLS `lm` with *dummy variables* would be more appropriate than a mixed-effects model. From a different perspective, the distribution of the $y$ values along each point in the $x1$ axis does not follow a Gaussian distributions both due to variations between units and within units, as is assumed of mixed-effects models.

As in one of the comments, the mixed-effects model would be more natural in a situation as in the `sleepstudy` {lme4} database, where different individuals respond to sleep deprivation with progressive increases in reaction time, and the heteroskedasticity seems to increase as times goes on:

```
require(lme4)
attach(sleepstudy)
fit <- lm(Reaction ~ Days)
plot(fit, pch=19, cex=0.5, col='slategray')
```

[image]

lending itself to fitting different intercepts and slopes for each of the Subjects:

```
plot(Reaction ~ Days, xlim=c(0, 9), ylim=c(200, 480), type='n', 
     xlab='Days', ylab='Reaction')

for (i in sleepstudy$Subject){
  points(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy[Subject==i,], pch=19, 
         cex = 0.5, col=i)
  fit<-lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject==i,])
  a <- predict(fit)
  lines(x=c(0:9),predict(fit), col=i, lwd=1)
}
```

[image]

This model would correspond to the `lme4` call `lmer(Reaction ~ Days +(Days|Subject))` which would result `coef(lmer(Reaction ~ Days +(Days|Subject)))` in a different intercept and slope for every subject. On the other hand `lmer(Reaction ~ Days +(1|Subject))` would produce different intercepts for each subject, *but* exactly the same slope for all subjects:

```
plot(Reaction ~ Days, xlim=c(0, 9), ylim=c(200, 480), type='n', 
     xlab='Days', ylab='Reaction')

for (i in sleepstudy$Subject){
  points(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy[Subject==i,], pch=19, 
         cex = 0.5, col=i)
  a<-coef(lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject)))$Subject[i,1]
  b<-coef(lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject)))$Subject[1,2]
  abline(a=a, b=b, col=i, lwd=1)
}
```

[image]

... clearly not as good a model as the relative AIC values also seem to indicate (`AIC(lmer(Reaction ~ Days +(1|Subject)), lmer(Reaction ~ Days +(Days|Subject))` `1794.465` v `1755.628`).