# Multiple regression in R results different to simple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interpretation

Hi I am having trouble acquiring the final results for presentation. 
The results from a multiple regression are different to my results in a simple linear regression.

For example, the multiple regression model
`mul <- lm(Response ~ Temp + Wave + Overcast, data = env)` gives me a p-value for 'Temp' of $0.01$, while the others are $>0.05$.

However, a simple linear regression `sim <- lm(Response ~ Temp, data =env)`
returns a p-value for 'Temp' of $0.03$.

Which result should I be presenting, and also how to I interpret the relationship between the predictors in the multiple regression?

Comment: Hint: look at the degrees of freedom for the t statistics in the simple and multiple linear regression. Then compare them.

Comment: There is a superb answer to this general question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830/28500). In the terminology of that answer, think of each linear regression coefficient as the result of _ignoring_ all of the other variables, while each multiple regression coefficient is _controlling for_ all the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two entirely different models. Which one you choose has a lot to do with experience in the field of study, aided by things such as adjusted R squares and ANOVA testing of both models side-by-side.

In multiple regression, the idea is that when we add a regressor ($x_2$) to a pre-existing model with just one regressor ($x_1$), we are regressing the "dependent variable" $y$ not over $x_2$, *but* over the residuals of the regression of $x_2$ over $x_1$. This changes everything.

If we set up the model as:

$y = \color{blue}{5}\, x_2 + \color{red}{15}\, x_1$ with both $x_1$ and $x_2$ generated as random $\sim N(0,1)$, the correlation $y$ with $x_1$ will be much higher than with $x_2$:

The regression of $y$ over $x_2$ in isolation will not capture the slope we set p of $5$, because $x_2$ will be compensating for the absence of the main explanatory variable in the model, i.e. $x_1$. The slope of $x_2$ will be, in fact, very close to the coefficient we assigned to $x_1$: $\color{red}{15}$. Leaving the intercept out, `summary(lm(y ~ x2 - 1))$coefficients` will return a slope of $\color{red}{15.42}$.

However, if we now include $x_1$ in the regression in a sneaky way, and instead of calling `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 - 1)`, we first regress $x_2$ over $x_1$ and keep the residuals before "tossing" $x_1$ as `errors <- residuals(lm(x2 ~ x1 - 1))` *and* then call `summary(lm(y ~ errors - 1))$coefficients` the slope will be $\color{blue}{4.681616}$, very close to the coefficient we set up for $x_2$, and... here comes the punch of the story... identical to coefficient for $x_2$ in `summary(lm(y ~ x2 + x1 - 1))$coefficients`: $x_2 \,\,\color{blue}{4.681616}$. The coefficient for $x_1$ will be $x_1 \,\,\color{red}{15.091305}$.

So ignoring the hidden confounder $x_1$ in the model $y \sim x_2$ forced $x_2$ to explain all by itself as much of the variation in $y$ as possible, resulting in a completely different slope as compared to the more accurate $y \sim x_1 + x_2$. You can check the concept of [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias).

It makes sense that the $p$-values are going to be significant in both instances, albeit different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply :)
However I've had cases where the relationship between a predictor and a dependent data was significant in a multiple regression but not significant in simple linear regression.. How would I interpret this? Would I try to find which other predictor is affecting the relationship and control for it?