# Holding other predictors constant via simulation in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, prediction, simulation

Imagine predicting `salary` of some professors from their years of experience (`time`) **controlling for/holding constant** their number of publications (`pubs`).

> **Question:** Is the following regarding the **meaning of holding constant** their number of `pubs` correct, and demonstrable via simulation in `R`?

Imagine we had countless professors, then take a sample of them with the exact same number of `pubs` (e.g., $1$).

- Fit a regression model with only `time` as predictor, get the regression coef of `time`.
- Take another sample with `pubs` of $2$, Fit the regression model again, get the regression coef of `time`.
- Keep changing `pubs` to $3, 4,…$ and each time get the regression coef of `time`.

At the end, **average** of our regression coefs of `time` will be a **partial regression coefficient** that has controlled for the `pubs` of professors while predicting `salary` from `time`.

> **p.s.** Is controlling for a predictor similar to *integrating it out*?

Comment: Isn't the coefficient of time in the straightforward model `salary ~ time + pubs` already a partial regression coefficient that has controlled for `pubs` (that is 435.3 in your code above)? Are you concerned with controlling for nonlinear effects in `pubs`?

Comment: @DexGroves, OP's question is about the deeper meaning of controlling for/holding constant a predictor (as s/he describes it) and whether this concept is demonstrable via an R simulation.

Comment: You would not want a simple average as that would put too much weight on cases with uncommon numbers of publications.

Comment: @Henry, would you please clarify via a simulation what you exactly mean?

Comment: Although this is one way to control for numbers of publications, note that it would be most closely related to a multiple regression in which `pubs` is introduced as a *categorical* variable rather than as a numerical count.  Concerning your PS, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables

Comment: @whuber, is a simulation possible?

Comment: What do you want to simulate and why?

Comment: @whuber, simulating the exact same scenario I describe in my question, to show that it holds, for instructional purposes and being able to produce helpful graphs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *if the model is correctly specified*.

Suppose your data is generated by
$$
y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon, \mbox{ where } E[\epsilon|x_1, x_2] = 0,
$$
i.e.
$$
E[y|x_1, x_2] = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2.
$$
Suppose $x_1$ is the predictor of interest and $x_2$ is control. Conditioning on the control $x_2$ gives
$$
E[y|x_2] = \beta_1 E[x_1|x_2] + \beta_2 x_2. \quad (*)
$$

The empirical counterpart of $(*)$ is the regression you're suggesting---regress $y$ on $x_1$ (with intercept) for a given value of $x_2$.
Note that for any given value of $x_2$, this regression conditional on $x_2$ is already a unbiased estimator of $\beta_1$.

Averaging over $x_2$ makes estimate less noisy. The assumption $E[\epsilon|x_1, x_2] = 0$ implies samples are uncorrelated across $x_2$. Therefore averaging over $x_2$ gives a smaller standard error.

**Comment**

The statement "the regression conditional on $x_2$ is a unbiased estimator of $\beta_1$" is contingent upon correct specification---correct functional form/no omitted variables/etc. In a real data set, you would have to willing to believe/claim true functional form is linear/no controls are omitted/etc.

If the true population regression function is not linear but $E[\epsilon|x_1, x_2] = 0$ still holds, I would expect averaging the OLS coefficient for $x_1$ from the regression conditional on $x_2$, call it $\hat{\beta}_1|x_2$, over $x_2$ to be close to the OLS coefficient $\hat{\beta}_1$.