# Simple linear regression vs Multiple Linear regression interpretation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interpretation

Suppose we have a multiple linear regression model with two predictors, $X_1$ and $X_2$:
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon.$$

We can interpret $\beta_1$ as the expected increase in $Y$ with a unit increase in $X_1$ when $X_2$ is held constant. This is because $\beta_1$ is the partial derivative of the expected value of $Y$ with respect to $X_1$.

Further, suppose that we also compute the simple linear regression of $Y$ against $X_1$:
$$Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + \epsilon.$$

Then I've seen by some authors that: $b_1$ is the expected increase in $Y$ with a unit increase in $X_1$ without holding $X_2$ constant.

But I really don't see the last point because for me in the simple linear regression is  like holding constant $X_2$ by giving it a zero value.

So why do they say the in the simple linear regression all other predictors not considered are not constant?

I would really appreciate if you can help me clarify this idea.

Comment: In a caual inference sense, when $X_2 $ is a confounder between $X_1 $ and $ Y $, the effects of $ X_1 $ to $ Y$ given $X_2 $ is different from effects of $ X_1 $ to $ Y$ without control/knowledge on $ X_2 $. The simple linear regression is describing the latter effects, where the information on $ X_1 $ will both has its original effects on $ Y$ and also the effects of $ X_1 $ to $X_2 $ to $ Y$. So that should be your case that $X_2 $ is not holding constant since the distribution on $X_2$ changes accordingly when $X_1 $ increase.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Bayesian. I'm still trying to understand the idea, but  the thing that bothers me is that algebraically speaking we can just plug in the value of $X_2 = 0$ in the multiple model, which converts it to a simple linear regression with just $X_1$ as a predictor and perform the regression. We held fixed $X_2$ at the value of zero.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you should read my answer to: [Is there a difference between 'controlling for' and 'ignoring' other variables in multiple regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830/7290), of which, this is nearly a duplicate.

---

To address your explicit question more directly, $X_2$ is *not* being held constant.  What you have done is set $\beta_2 = 0$, not adjust the data to account for what they would be like if $X_2$ were $0$ for all data in the dataset.

Unless $X_1$ and $X_2$ were perfectly uncorrelated *in your dataset*, controlling for $X_2$ would amount to shifting the $X_1$ values to some degree.  As a result, the estimated $\hat\beta_1$s between the two models would differ.

Answer (score 0):

Try estimating the two models on some dataset:

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \epsilon$$

and

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$$

What you would usually notice is that the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ parameters *differ* between the two models. In the second you control for $X_2$, in the first one you don't, hence the different parameter estimates. In the first model, by the fact that we didn't include $X_2$, it was accounted for by noise term $\epsilon$. If in the second model you set $X_2=0$ you would consider only the scenario where it is exactly zero. So in fact, in simple linear regression, all the other predictors are accounted for by the *random* noise, rather than considered constant.