# Causal links with omitted variables

Tags: regression, bias, causality

So I have a fairly basic setup, with $X\rightarrow Y$. However, I've run across a potential third variable, Z, that is probably correlated with both X and Y. However, the causality for Z is unusual for an omitted variable bias. All the examples of omitted variables I've read have the causality $Z\rightarrow X$ and $Z\rightarrow Y$. In my model, however, the causality is reversed: $X\rightarrow Z$ and $Y\rightarrow Z$. Do I still need to include Z in my regression because it is correlated with both variables, or can I squeak my way out of it because causality runs in the other direction?

Comment: I believe that in your casual graph, $Z$ can be called a "collider" and according to wikipedia, you should be cautious about adjusting for a collider: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collider_%28epidemiology%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you regress $y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$ instead of the long regression $y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \delta Z_i + \epsilon_i$, the omitted variable bias formula is
$$\widehat{\beta} = \beta + \delta \frac{Cov(X_i,Z_i)}{Var(X_i)} $$

For a proof of this see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43343/derivation-of-the-effect-of-unmodeled-confounders-on-ols-estimates/94927#94927). This shows you that the bias relates to the covariances. For this point it matters little whether $X$ causes $Z$ or vice versa. Given that $Cov(X_i,Z_i)\neq 0$ and $\delta \neq 0$ (since $Z$ is related to $Y$, again the way of causation does not make a difference), your short regression will suffer from omitted variable bias.

[edit]
To address the comments it should also be mentioned that the long regression is not without problems either. Including a variable in a regression that in itself is an outcome that is determined by the dependent variable leads to the problem of "bad controls" (see section 3.2.3 in [Angrist and Pischke](http://egei.vse.cz/english/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/mostly+harmeless+econometrics.pdf), p. 47). So whether you use the long- or the short-regression you will get biased estimates in either case. The typical solution would be to omit $Z_i$ from the model (I assume it is unobserved which is the reason for it to be an omitted variable in the first place) and to use an [instrumental variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/instrumental-variables/info) for $X_i$.

Comment: But typically, one wouldn't want to control for an *intermediate* variable, eg $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$.  Your algebra still holds of course, but controlling for $Z$ would be removing some of $X$'s bona-fide influence on $Y$.  Can you address that point in your answer?

Comment: @AndrewM I hope the extended discussion addresses your concern.