# Derivation of IV estimator using Linear Algebra

Tags: instrumental-variables

Im aware of the question [Derivation of IV estimator?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64279/derivation-of-iv-estimator) on this site.

Im interested however in obtaining the way we derive it using linear algebra.

$$\beta^{IV}=(Z'X)^{-1}Z'Y$$

the reason why I ask is to obtain a clearer picture of how exactly we get this equation.

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you mean by a derivation "using linear algebra"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer to this question is that we know that OLS is the solution to
$$
(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)
$$
w.r.t. to $\beta$.

The 2SLS estimator $\beta^{2SLS}=(X'P_ZX)^{-1}X'P_Zy$ is the solution to 
$$
(y-X\beta)'P_Z(y-X\beta),
$$
where $P_Z$ is the (symmetric) projection matrix $P_Z=Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$.

The IV formula you quote results under exact identification, so that $X'Z$ is square and the expression for 2SLS simplifies accordingly, noting that
$$
(X'Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X)^{-1}=(Z'X)^{-1}(Z'Z)(X'Z)^{-1}.
$$